# A Geometry Problem involving congruency

Tags: geometry

O is the circumcenter of $\Delta$ ABC. M is the mid-point of the median through A. Join OM and produce it to N such that OM=MN. Show that, N lies on the altitude through A.

Ratio of Orthocenter, Centroid, Circumcenter is 2:1 but it does not help much...

Please Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $D$ be the midpoint of $BC$, it is obvious that $ANDO$ is a parallelogram, hence, $AN || OD$. Note that $OD$ is perpendicular to $BC$, therefore, $AN$ is perpendicular to $BC$, or in other words, $N$ lies on the altitude through $A$.